# Spring Social with Liferay

Tags: spring-mvc, liferay, liferay-6, spring-social

I am currently developing an  application in Liferay 6.1 GA2 and I would like to use the Spring Social services.

It would be great help if anybody can share some documents, links or sample code.

Thanks
Gautam

Comment: Google is your friend. http://www.springsource.org/spring-social

Comment: Use Spring Social Services to do what?

Comment: @MaheshGuruswamy thanks for reply..already went through these links for those are for non portal projects

Comment: @CharlesForsythe for authentication using Twitter,Facebook and write something on wall.

Comment: @Gautam, seems like Liferay is open source and java based. You would hook into spring social just like you would hook into any other spring based API. What have you tried so far? I doubt if you would find any end to end tutorial.

Comment: @MaheshGuruswamy  i am going through below link  https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social/wiki/Quick-Start